# MATLAB: How do I graph multiple functions on the same graph?

Tags: matlab, function, math, graph, plot

How can I graph multiple functions on the same graph/plot/Cartesian plane on MATLAB with domain and range restrictions?

For example I made up the following functions below. How would I graph the following on the same graph within MATLAB?

```
Function 1: x = -3 for 10 <= y <= 14
Function 2: y = -2x for -5 <= x <= -4
Function 3: (x-0)^2 + (y-12)^2 = 2.25 // Produces a circle
Function 4: y = 4 for -1 <= x <= 1
```

Comment: have you tried to use `plot` ?

Comment: I've read that you can use a command called     ezplot(func) but I don't know how to incorporate restrictions into that.

Comment: use logical conditions. try to search for it in SO I'm sure there's plenty of examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab is a numerical computing environment, so you'll need to tell it what you're looking for while plotting.

In the case of your first example, you'll need to tell it which Y values to plot.  Since X is always the same, you know it's going to be a line - so two points will be enough.  Plot requires parallel arrays, so:

**Function 1:** `x = [-3 -3]; y = [10 14]; plot(x, y);`

To plot additional lines on the same graph, use the command `hold on`, which applies to the figure you just plotted.  If you don't do this, new plot commands will erase the old plots.

Similarly,

**Function 2:** `x = [-5 4]; y = -2*x; plot(x, y);`

For circles/ellipses like #3, `ezplot` can be helpful, although you still have to specify the range.

**Function 3:** `ezplot('x^2 + (y-12)^2 - 2.25', [-3,3,10,14])`

The last one is easy, but let's say it were a curve instead.  You'd want to plot more than just two x values.  You can create a vector from a range like this: `x = -1:0.1:1;`, or an evenly space set of points from -1 to 1, with an interval of 0.1.  Let's say you want to plot it on the same graph, and you've already done `hold on`.  You want a different color, and you want to show the individual points that make up the line, you can use the third argument to the plot function:

**Function 4:** `x = -1:0.1:1; y = 4 * ones(length(x)); plot(x, y, '-r.');`

The second command here, `y = 4 * ones(length(x));` simply creates a y vector that is the same length as x.